Particular solution $x'=Ax+\cos(\alpha t)d+\sin(\alpha t)d $
Let be $A\in R^{n \times n},x_0,c,d\in R^n$ and $\alpha \in R-\{0\}$.
Prove that the system
$$x'=Ax+\cos(\alpha t)c+\sin(\alpha t)d $$
$$x(0)=x_0$$
has a particular solution of the form
$\varphi_p(t)=\cos(\alpha t)v+\sin(\alpha t)w$
where $v,w\in R^n$ are constants, if and only if
$$(A^2+\alpha^2 I)x_0= -(Ac+\alpha d)$$
Is this problem correct?
My attemp:
From the system we can obtain
$$\varphi''=A^2\varphi+ \cos(\alpha t)(Ac+\alpha d)+\sin(\alpha t) (Ad-\alpha c)$$
But for the hypothesis
$\varphi''(t)=-\alpha^2\varphi(t)$.
In consequence:
$$-\alpha^2 \varphi=A^2\varphi+ \cos(\alpha t)(Ac+\alpha d)+\sin(\alpha t) (Ad-\alpha c)$$
$$(A^2+\alpha^2)\varphi(t)= -\cos(\alpha t)(Ac+\alpha d)-\sin(\alpha t) (Ad-\alpha c)$$
In $t=0$ meet the condition.
Up to this point, everything is fine,but I don't know how to use this last condition to get the particular solution, since the condition is with $x_0$, so I only know how the second derivative of the function behaves in t=0.
Can you give some advice?

Where is $x_0$ from in $(A^2+\alpha^2 I)x_0= -(Ac+\alpha d)$?

In the second line, you have two $d$s. I guess one should be $c$.

Just insert the particular solution also on the left side and compare the coefficients of the trigonometric terms. If you do this to the second derivative or as in the answer of xpaul in the first derivative is a question of taste, both approaches have their elegance.

Note
$$\varphi_p'(t)=-\alpha\sin(\alpha t)v+\alpha\cos(\alpha t)w$$
and hence
$$\varphi_p'=A\varphi_p+\cos(\alpha t)c+\sin(\alpha t)d $$
becomes
$$-\alpha\sin(\alpha t)v+\alpha\cos(\alpha t)w=A(\cos(\alpha t)v+\sin(\alpha t)w)+\cos(\alpha t)c+\sin(\alpha t)d.$$
Comparing the coefficients of $\cos(\alpha t)$ and $\sin(\alpha t)$ gives
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha w=Av+c, -\alpha v=Aw+d.
\end{eqnarray}
From this, one has
$$ (A^2+\alpha^2I)v=-Ac-\alpha d, (A^2+\alpha^2I)w=-Ad+\alpha c.$$

In the last line, the equations must be with $A^2+\alpha^2 I$

@Renatolorentz, thanks.
